# How to query elasticsearch to get nested property

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am very new to elasticsearch and am trying to put together a query (in Kibana) for the following json data:

```
{
    "RepoCount": 2,
    "ThirdPartyRepoCount": 1,
    "RepoReadMeCount": 1,
    "date": "2019-10-25 12:02:41",
    "projects": [
        {
            "key": "GA",
            "id": 884,
            "name": "Company Archive",
            "description": "An archive for old dormant or abandoned git projects",
            "type": "NORMAL",
            "Repos": [
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "name": "address",
                    "scmId": "git",
                    "NumberFiles": 319,
                    "HasReadMe": false,
                    "GitRepoUrl": "blablabla.git",
                    "LastCommitDate": "08/16/2013",
                },
                {
                    "id": 364,
                    "name": "api",
                    "scmId": "git",
                    "NumberFiles": 377,
                    "HasReadMe": false,
                    "GitRepoUrl": "blablabla.git",
                    "LastCommitDate": "07/01/2014",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to write queries to get to the data under projects and 'Repos'.
I have imported the json data into an index called `gitrepos` and successfully created an index pattern. I've tried queries like:

`GET gitrepos/projects/_search`
`GET gitrepos/projects/REPOS/_search`

But with no luck.
The only thing I can get to work is this:
`GET gitrepos`
which merely gives me everything back.
I'd like to drill down deeper, but the above is not working.
How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is named `gitrepos`, so your search endpoint is `GET /gitrepos/_search`. Each document in the index will be something like your above document; you can return documents which have Repos matching some conditions.

```
GET gitrepos/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "projects.Repos.GitRepoUrl": "blablabla.git" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For more complex searches where you want to match on multiple fields in a single document, you would need to use a [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

If you want to search individual Repo documents directly, you would need to index each of those elements in their own index.

Comment: So my endpoint stays pretty basic, and it's the match or term queries that allow me to drill down?

Comment: The search endpoint is the index, not subdocuments within the index. You'll use the Elasticsearch query language to query on specific terms within those subdocuments. Elasticsearch will return the full document for each of your matches, unless you filter it down.

Comment: And in my case it has been returning the full document, which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: It sounds to me like you probably want to reindex your data with your individual git repos as the documents. You can probably make your existing data work(ish) but it's going to be quite a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I did yesterday. Each 'GitRepo' is now it's own document.